# Subroutines defined in required file assigned to wrong namespace after use of custom module

Tags: perl, module, namespaces

In a script I am working on, I have something similar to the following:

```
require "environment.pm"; # Various definitions, including subroutine get_coll()
use Custom::Module;
```

In the `Custom::Module` file, I start with

```
package Custom::Module;
```

and end with

```
1;
```

When I try to call `get_coll()` I get an error about it:

> ( main::get_coll() ) being undefined.

If I require `Custom::Module` instead of using or change the call to be

```
Custom::Module::get_coll();
```

it works fine. This leads me to be believe that the "use" statement of `CustomModule` is changing the "active" namespace so when `get_coll()` is processed (since it is processed at the time of calling) it gets assigned to that namespace instead of main.  This doesn't seem to be an issue with regular perl modules, but from the ones I've looked through, I haven't noticed anything different that would cause the namespace to "revert" back to main after the module has loaded.  Any help in better understanding the namespace usage or fixing the module to not cause this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Side note: It isn't a huge issue for me to just "require" the module, but it was unexpected behavior to me so I mostly just want to better understand why what happened happened.

Comment: It's `package` that does that, not `use`. That's the whole point of `package`.

Comment: I think you are mistaken. If you test carefully you will find that, if `use Custom::Module` doesn't allow you to call `get_coll` directly, then neither does `require Custom::Module`. If you implement `Custom::Module` correctly using `Exporter` *and also* `use Custom::Module` then it will import the symbol into the calling code's namespace. Otherwise you must fully-qualify it as `Custom::Module::get_coll`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to recreate the files exactly as you describe them. Here are my three source files

You say

> In a script I am working on, I have something similar to the following:
>
> ```
> require "environment.pm"; # Various definitions, including subroutine get_coll()
> use Custom::Module;
> ```

and

> When I try to call get_coll() I get an error about it

Although you don't say where you're calling `get_coll`, I guess it's in the main script and I think that amounts to this script file

**my_script.pl**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

require 'environment.pm';

use Custom::Module;

say get_coll();
```

and this module file

**environment.pm**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

sub get_coll {
  return 'coll';
}

1;
```

And then you say

> In the `Custom::Module` file, I start with
>
> ```
> package Custom::Module;
> ```
>
> and end with
>
> ```
> 1;
> ```

So I wrote this module file. It doesn't have any contents because you didn't describe any

**Custom/Module.pm**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

package Custom::Module;

1;
```

Now, when I run `my_script.pl` I get

```
coll
```

with no warnings or error messages, which is exactly as I expected

***I am concerned that you say `environment.pm` contains `get_coll`, yet you are able to call `Custom::Module::get_coll`. Does `Custom/Module.pm` also have a `require 'environment.pm'`?***

If you can point out where I have misinterpreted your description then please do, as I cannot replicate your problem at present and so am unable to help you

Otherwise, I recommend that you play with these three files to create a [*Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example*](http://sscce.org/) of your problem. That will help us enormously to find a solution for you

Comment: Ah... I think you are on to something. The file with the get_coll subroutine IS also require'd in the Custom::Module package. Since it was being use'd, then it would load that subroutine in that namespace!

So simple of an error. Thanks for your help and explanations!

Comment: @Fincher: You're welcome. In general you should stick to `use` rather thasn `require` unless you have a good reason to do otherwise

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken about `require` being any different from `use` with respect to what namespace subroutines get defined in. It is not. And you are mistaken about `use` affecting the current package. It does not.

```
# Custom/Module.pm
package Custom::Module;
# the namespace is now "Custom::Module"
sub foo { ... }  # defines  &Custom::Module::foo
sub bar { ... }  # defines  &Custom::Module::bar
1;   # end of Custom/Module.pm

---

# mainScript.pl
# without an explicit 'package' statement, we are in namespace "main"
use Custom::Module;    # parses Custom/Module.pm
# but when the 'use' statement is complete, we are still in namespace "main"
sub baz { ... }   # defines  &main::baz
$x = baz();       # calls &main::baz
$y = foo();       # calls &main::foo, error if main::foo not defined
$z = Custom::Module::bar();  # calls &Custom::Module::bar
...
```

The comments describe what namespace we are in in each part of each file. None of that would be any different if we said `require Custom::Module` instead of `use Custom::Module`.

Now it can be a hassle to keep typing `Custom::Module::bar()` all the time when there is no `main::bar()` and there's no ambiguity about which `bar` subroutine you would be referring to. The key to getting perl to recognize your call to `bar` as referring to `Custom::Module::bar` is to copying the subroutine reference from `Custom::Module` into your current namespace. That is, making `main::bar()` refer to the same subroutine as `Custom::Module::bar()`.

The canonical way to do this is with the [`Exporter`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Exporter) module. The low level way to do this (and what `Exporter` does behind the scenes) is to manipulate perl's symbol tables.

For your specific problem, you would use `Exporter` like this:

```
 # Custom/Module.pm
 package Custom::Module;
 use base 'Exporter';      # make Custom::Module inherit from Exporter
 our @EXPORT = qw(foo bar);
 sub foo { ... }
 sub bar { ... }
 ...
 1;
```

Now any other file that calls `use Custom::Module` will get the function `get_coll` imported into its namespace. This gets done behind the scenes in `Exporter` by manipulating the symbol table. Specifically, calling `use Custom::Module` from package `main` will get `Exporter` to make a typeglob assignment like

```
*main::foo = *Custom::Module::foo;
```

and this will make your function call from `main::foo()` invoke the code that was defined in `Custom::Module::foo()`.

Comment: Recently, it is recognised that *importing* from `Exporter` is better than *subclassing* it. So `use base 'Exporter'` should be `use Exporter 'import'`. Also, `*main::foo = *Custom::Module::foo` copies the entire `foo` glob, and should be `*main::foo = \&Custom::Module::foo`

Comment: Unless you say `@EXPORT = qw(&foo)`, `Exporter` will also copy the entire `foo` glob.

Comment: No, it won't. See [***How to Export*** in the `Exporter` documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Exporter#How-to-Export) which says *“The symbols must be given by full name with the exception that the ampersand in front of a function is optional”*. I admit that's not definitive about what else may be exported, but the empirical truth is that `use Module 'foo'` imports *only* `&Module::foo` and not `@Module::foo`, `$Module::foo` etc.

Comment: I understand your comment, but don't feel like it addresses my main issue that I don't understand.

Comment: I have subroutine get_coll() in file1.pm.
I have other subroutines in a file with package Custom::Package.<br/> 

If I only require "file1.pm" I can call get_coll() in main.pl and it works.
If I add "use Custom::Package", then get_coll() is no longer in the main namespace.  I can call the function if I change the call to Custom::Package::get_coll().
If I change "use Custom::Package" to "require Custom::Package" the "get_coll()" works again.

Seems pretty obviously a namespace issue, no?

Comment: @Fincher: Okay, that sounds pretty much the same as you wrote in the question except that, confusingly, you've changed the names of the files. Please take a look at my solution, where I've created three files that match your description. I can't make them behave as you describe, so you should copy what I have written and make minimal changes so that it displays the same behaviour as you're seeing